# How can I make an popup box animation after AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Usually, when users click save button, it will popup a small green box or some kind of animation that says *'save successfully'*. How can I do such thing in my AJAX's `success`?

I use `.each()` loop and wordpress for multiple stuffs, you can ignore it.
Also, I want to know can I make animation inside the button in the beforehand, I have tried `.html()`, but it does not work, it has to be `.val()`

jQuery:

```
jQuery.each( elements, function(text_name, text_number){
    $('#' + text_name + '_save_button').on('click', function(){
        var cure_textarea = $('#' + text_name + '_t').val();
        var data = { 
            action        : 'cure_way_textarea',
            text_number   : text_number,
            cure_textarea : cure_textarea,
            userVoteNonce : UserAjaxVote.userVoteNonce,
        };
        $.ajax({
            url        : UserAjaxVote.ajaxurl,
            type       : 'POST',
            cache      : false,
            data       : data,
            beforeSend : function() {
                $('#' + text_name + '_save_button').val('saving...');
            },
            success    : function(data){
                $('#' + text_name + '_save_button').val('Save');
            }
        });//ajax
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="good_save_button" value="save"/>
```

Comment: there are numerous notification/alert plugins you can use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a popup like this isn't too hard.  What I do is create the popup in html like so first:

```
<div class="success-popup">Success!</div>
```

Now CSS:

```
.success-popup{
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-150px;
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background:green;
  color:white;
  z-index:100;
  display:none;
}
```

Then in the success function in the AJAX call, I just show the popup.  Then I set a timer to go off in a few seconds after that which will hide it again.

```
//this is in the 'success' function for an ajax post
$('.success-popup').show();
  setTimeout(function(){
  $('.success-popup').hide();
},3000)
```

That will effectively show a green popup with the text "success" right in the middle of your screen and remove it after 3 seconds.  Of course you can change the position and the time.  I use this code all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap modal
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

and call to modal in success function:

```
success: function(data){
   $('#saveModal .modal-title').text('Saved!');
   $('#saveModal .modal-body p').text('Save ok.');
   $('#saveModal').modal('show');
}
```

My english not good so I hope you can understand and ignore my error in words.

Comment: Thanks for your time, actually I am not very familiar with bootstrap modal, is that a plugin or a framework?